# HTML head tags in wrong order

Tags: html, css, header, semantics

[image]

In this layout it's not valid because H1 isn't the first rendered head element... is this a terrible sin or is it ok?  Any way to fix this?  Both columns are variable length so I don't see any way round this.

**Citation**

Someone asked me to citate this:

http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/ert-19991221.html#Technique3.5.A

> Header elements (H1-H6) should be checked to ensure they are nested according to the following rules
>   The first header element in the document must be H1
>   There must be only one H1 element in the document
>   Header levels must not increase by more than 1 level. Example: H2 following H1 is good. H3 following H1 is bad.
>   Header elements can decrease by any level. Example: H2 following H5 is OK.

Comment: Depends entirely on the semantics of the document. Can you explain what each header describes?

Comment: @eric, here is a working URL: http://69.24.73.172/demos/newdemo/  using that layout

Comment: Ta. Willing to use HTML5 for more semantic meaning?

Comment: @eric, yes I want to make this document as accessible and semantically correct as I can

Comment: Also, you might want to check out the [html5 outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)

Comment: @Tom - That citation is to an obsolete draft. The latest version, and still only a working draft, is here: http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/#logical-heading. Notice that it doesn't require starting at H1 and doesn't state that there should only be one H1 element. It is not, in any case, a web authoring guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h2>`s should be interpretable as subheadings of some `<h1>`.

In HTML5, you can define the document hierarchy by nesting `<section>` tags, and completely ignoring the `<h1>` - `<h6>` tags. You can see an HTML5 document outliner [here](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/), which illustrates this property.

Of course, the simplest fix is to just float your columns in the other order. At present they are both floated left. Switch the order in the markup, float 'em right, and suddenly, the headings are in the right order!

---

<sup>On a side note, the semantics of the 'This Weeks Spotlight' section of [your site](http://69.24.73.172/demos/newdemo/) is wrong. It should be more like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/2sCGz/.)</sup>

Comment: But there should only be one H1 one the page right?  Which is why it should be the first rendered header.

Answer (score 5):

Where the different tags are rendered is not important, it's all about semantics. `H1` simply means that the heading is higher level than `H2`, `H3`, etc.

Comment: Some strict HTML analysers specify that H1 should be the first Hx tag on the page.

Comment: You're right, I've seen a few of those, but does anyone else care? Sure, you could probably figure out a way to place your `H1` before all the rest and then use a bunch of CSS to get things positioned as you wanted them, but I'm sure it will take even longer to find an HTML interpreter (browser, search engine spider, …) that actually cares about this detail. To answer your question in your own terms: no, it's not a terrible sin ;)

Comment: W3C Validator has no issue with Hx tags being 'out of order' (Strict)

Comment: @jakub, I've added a citation to question

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big of a deal it is that H1 isn't the first thing on the page.  I know Google will look at headings to try to establish context.  They say that there should only be one H1 tag, for example, and that it should be a good short heading that describes the content of the page.  In general, the text (or subheadings) underneath the h1 should then follow suit describing what your content is about in greater and greater detail.  That's the theory anyway.

In any case, what about something like this?

```
<body>
    <div style="float: right; width: 25%;">
        <h1>your h1 text</h1>   
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 75%;">
        content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```